# Split a dataframe string column by two different delimiters

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

The following is my dataset:

```
Itemcode

DB9450//DB9450/AD9066

DA0002/DE2396//DF2345

HWC72

GG7183/EB6693

TA444/B9X8X4:7-2-
```

The following is the code I have been trying to use

```
df.withColumn("item1", split(col("Itemcode"), "/").getItem(0)).withColumn("item2", split(col("Itemcode"), "/").getItem(1)).withColumn("item3", split(col("Itemcode"), "//").getItem(0))
```

But it fails when there is a double slash in between first and second item and also fails when there is a double slash between 2nd and 3rd item

```
Desired output is:

  item1    item2     item3

DB9450 DB9450 AD9066

DA0002 DE2396 DF2345

HWC72

GG7183 EB6693

TA444  B9X8X4
```

Comment: can you please check and confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace the // with / then you can split.. Please try the below and let us know if worked
**Input**

```
df_b = spark.createDataFrame([('DB9450//DB9450/AD9066',"a"),('DA0002/DE2396//DF2345',"a"),('HWC72',"a"),('GG7183/EB6693',"a"),('TA444/B9X8X4:7-2-',"a")],[ "reg","postime"])
```

---

```
+--------------------+-------+
|                 reg|postime|
+--------------------+-------+
|DB9450//DB9450/AD...|      a|
|DA0002/DE2396//DF...|      a|
|               HWC72|      a|
|       GG7183/EB6693|      a|
|   TA444/B9X8X4:7-2-|      a|
+--------------------+-------+
```

**Logic**

```
df_b = df_b.withColumn('split_col', F.regexp_replace(F.col('reg'), "//", "/"))
df_b = df_b.withColumn('split_col', F.split(df_b['split_col'], '/'))
df_b = df_b.withColumn('col1' , F.col('split_col').getItem(0))
df_b = df_b.withColumn('col2' , F.col('split_col').getItem(1))
df_b = df_b.withColumn('col2', F.regexp_replace(F.col('col2'), ":7-2-", ""))
df_b = df_b.withColumn('col3' , F.col('split_col').getItem(2))
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------+-------+--------------------+------+------+------+
|                 reg|postime|           split_col|  col1|  col2|  col3|
+--------------------+-------+--------------------+------+------+------+
|DB9450//DB9450/AD...|      a|[DB9450, DB9450, ...|DB9450|DB9450|AD9066|
|DA0002/DE2396//DF...|      a|[DA0002, DE2396, ...|DA0002|DE2396|DF2345|
|               HWC72|      a|             [HWC72]| HWC72|  null|  null|
|       GG7183/EB6693|      a|    [GG7183, EB6693]|GG7183|EB6693|  null|
|   TA444/B9X8X4:7-2-|      a|[TA444, B9X8X4:7-2-]| TA444|B9X8X4|  null|
+--------------------+-------+--------------------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: The :7-2- is not a fixed value. I need to remove any text after the last delimiter at the end of the string, in this case, it is :

Comment: If you have the item code has fixed value : sub-string can be used df_b = df_b.withColumn('col2', df_b['col2'].substr(0, 6))

Answer (score 0):

Processing the text as csv works well for this.

First, let's read in the text, replacing double backslashes along the way

Edit: Also removing everything after a colon

```
val items = """
Itemcode

DB9450//DB9450/AD9066

DA0002/DE2396//DF2345

HWC72

GG7183/EB6693

TA444/B9X8X4:7-2-

""".replaceAll("//", "/").split(":")(0)
```

Get the max number of items in a row
to create an appropriate header

```
val numItems = items.split("\n").map(_.split("/").size).reduce(_ max _)

val header = (1 to numItems).map("Itemcode" + _).mkString("/")
```

Then we're ready to create a Data Frame

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "/")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(spark.sparkContext.parallelize((header + items).split("\n")).toDS)
  .filter("Itemcode1 <> 'Itemcode'")

df.show(false)


+---------+-----------+---------+
|Itemcode1|Itemcode2  |Itemcode3|
+---------+-----------+---------+
|DB9450   |DB9450     |AD9066   |
|DA0002   |DE2396     |DF2345   |
|HWC72    |null       |null     |
|GG7183   |EB6693     |null     |
|TA444    |B9X8X4     |null     |
+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is useful (**`spark>=2.4`**)-

**`split`** and **`TRANSFORM`** spark sql function will do the magic as below-

### Load the provided test data

```scala
val data =
      """
        |Itemcode
        |
        |DB9450//DB9450/AD9066
        |
        |DA0002/DE2396//DF2345
        |
        |HWC72
        |
        |GG7183/EB6693
        |
        |TA444/B9X8X4:7-2-
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString("|"))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", "|")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------------------+
      * |Itemcode             |
      * +---------------------+
      * |DB9450//DB9450/AD9066|
      * |DA0002/DE2396//DF2345|
      * |HWC72                |
      * |GG7183/EB6693        |
      * |TA444/B9X8X4:7-2-    |
      * +---------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Itemcode: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Use `split` and `TRANSFORM` (you can run this query directly in pyspark)

```scala
    df.withColumn("item_code", expr("TRANSFORM(split(Itemcode, '/+'), x -> split(x, ':')[0])"))
      .selectExpr("item_code[0] item1", "item_code[1] item2", "item_code[2] item3")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------+------+------+
      * |item1 |item2 |item3 |
      * +------+------+------+
      * |DB9450|DB9450|AD9066|
      * |DA0002|DE2396|DF2345|
      * |HWC72 |null  |null  |
      * |GG7183|EB6693|null  |
      * |TA444 |B9X8X4|null  |
      * +------+------+------+
      */
```